# Scrolling in text file in C

Tags: c, text-files, fgetc

I have a problem with C language. I have to find and print every second word from input text file to output text file between words `START` and `STOP`. I make a function, which control if is next word in text file `STOP`. But if is in input text file word `SToP`, function `fgetc` move to T and check, that next letter is not O and break... But I need to get before word `SToP`. How can I do this? I cant use any library functions except for `fgetc`, `fputc`, `fopen` nad `fclose`.

Here is code:

```
int search_STOP(int ch, FILE* in) { if(ch == 'S'){
  ch = fgetc(in);
  if(ch =='T'){
    ch = fgetc(in);
    if(ch == 'O'){       
       ch = fgetc(in);
       if(ch == 'P'){       
             return 1;
       }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not first convert char case to upper or lower and then check?

Comment: I would start by writing a function that reads a whole word a character at a time. Check if the word is special after you have read the whole word.

Comment: What does the title of this question have to do with the actual question? The question has nothing to do with _"scrolling"_.

Comment: Firstly, scrolling - I meant that I need to get back in the string in text file.

Comment: Secondly, I cant use any library functions - toupper, tolower + I have to print in output file the same word (StOp -> StOp) from input file...

Comment: You can write your own toupper and tolower functions if you know ASCII

Comment: Yes, I can do this... but I need the SAME word write in output file. For example if in the input file is sentence "Hello, STOp Kitty, hoW aRe yoU StOP" I have to write in output file the same sentence...

Comment: For input, implement a function that reads one word consisting of alphanumeric characters into a buffer. For output, implement `puts` (using `fputc` on successive indices of a string until you hit the `\0` at the end). The case-insensitive comparison is trivial (e.g., `if ((buf[0] == 's' || buf[0] == 'S') && (buf[1] == 't' || buf([1] == 'T') && … && buf[4] == '\0')`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem once. Most of these problems you can solve by googling and stitching code snippets together.

I changed the code I made back then a little for your purpose (since the job I was performing was slightly more complex than just ignoring case in the searchword). Note that it is important that you provide your search word ("start") in **lower case** in this piece of code. You could change it so that it also takes upper case search words but I'll leave that to you to figure out on your own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int specialFind(char *buffer, const char *s, int startIndex, int endIndex);

int specialFind(char *buffer, const char *s, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int findIndex = 0;

    int s_len = 0;
    int signComp = 0;

    while(s[s_len] != '\0')
    {
        s_len++;
    }

    char msg[64];

    for(int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        if(buffer[i] >= 65 && buffer[i] <= 90)
        {
            signComp = 32;
        }
        else
        {
            signComp = 0;
        }
        if(buffer[i] + signComp == s[findIndex])
        {
            findIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            findIndex = 0;
        }
        if(findIndex == s_len)
        {
            return i - s_len + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fileptr;

    //  First opening and reading to determine file size
    fileptr = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");
    int filelen = 0;
    char c;
    while(1)
    {
        c = fgetc(fileptr);
        filelen++;
        if(feof(fileptr))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fileptr);

    //  Now we're actually gonna read the file to the buffer
    char buffer[filelen];
    fileptr = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");
    int index = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        buffer[index] = fgetc(fileptr);
        index++;
        if(feof(fileptr))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fileptr);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is good and correct, but I cant use any library function. In your code you have fread, fseek, snprintf... I have to use only fgetc, fputc, fopen and fclose...

Comment: Yea well the printfs at the end were for me to verify if the output was correct. With just fopen, fclose and fgetc you can do the same stuff I did with fseek and fread, see the updated code.